# What is wrong with my inline foreach/if statement?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
int[][] multi = new int[2][];

multi[0] = new int[2];
multi[1] = new int[2];

multi[0][0] = 11;
multi[0][1] = 2;
multi[0][2] = 4;

multi[1][0] = 4;
multi[1][1] = 5;
multi[1][2] = 6;

Array.ForEach(
  multi, 
  x => multi.Length != x.Length 
    ? throw new Exception("The two dimensional arrays must be symmetrical."));
```

I get an **overflow exception** and i not sure what I'm trying to do here can be done?

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: `multi[0] = new int[2];` creates an array of length = 2. Then `multi[0][2] = 4;` tries to set the 3rd element of the array.

Comment: For a Duplicate like this, can we edit the Typo System.IndexOutOfRangeException out of the question?

Answer (score 3):

The *immediate cause* of the error is

```
multi[0] = new int[2]; // multi[0] has 2 items: with indexes 0 and 1

...

multi[0][2] = 4;       // out of range: multi[0] doesn't have 3d item (with index 2)
```

You may want to change the initialization into

```
int[][] multi = new int[][] {
  new int[] { 11, 2, 4},
  new int[] {  4, 5, 6},
};
```

You are working with *jagged*, not *2D* array; that's why the test (we want `multi` to be *square* array) should be

```
using System.Linq;

...

if (multi.Any(x => x == null || multi.Length != x.Length))
  throw new Exception("The two dimensional arrays must be symmetrical.");
```

**Remark**: do not throw *general* `Exception`, but *specific* one, say `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` etc.

Comment: And the fact that he can't use a ternary operator like that in a lambda :)